How to escape conflicts of CSS between two UI Frameworks in Vue3?
We decided to move from one UI framework to another (from early BootstrapVueNext 0.7.3 to PrmeVue v3 or v4) and have style conflicts. The Doprdown component style or the Button component style is broken if we try to use both frameworks.
So is there a clear way to resolve these style conflicts?
And this is my way to plug in css:
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap-vue-next/dist/bootstrap-vue-next.css";
import "primevue/resources/themes/aura-light-green/theme.css";

And how can I use CSS layers, for example, or is it not a correct solution? Primevue v3 has a CSS layer primevue by default, but BootstrapVueNext hasn't.

To resolve this issue, if you have several UI frameworks, import components of this by using a prefix in import notations like this:
import PButton from 'primevue/button';
import PDropdown from 'primevue/dropdown';

So in my case, it helped me to resolve conflict between BootstrapVueNext and PrmeVue button and dropdown components:)

Feel free to accept your own answer.
